# Is there a way to force a remote refresh via the iOS Remote Web Inspector?

Tags: safari, development

I'm using iOS 6's new remote web inspector feature, which is pretty nice.

Is there a way of forcing a page refresh on the remote iOS device from the desktop - it's just a bit easier then reaching over and refreshing the page on the device itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, figured it out, it's a bit kludgy, but works.

In the javascript console (the single line at the bottom of the web inspector) - type this:

```
document.location.reload();
```

This forces a page reload on the remote device.

Comment: Cool. I didn’t know there was a javascript console. I will delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

While having the Safari Web Inspector focussed, press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> on your keyboard.

It's faster than typing `document.location.reload();`. Further, it doens't matter in which tab you are (Console, Elements, Debugger, or any other tab), so that also also makes it faster than going to the Console Tab, pressing <kbd>Arrow up</kbd> follewed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>.